# Error while sending email using SMTP & exchange server office365.com

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send email from my controller (MVC4) through exchange server i.e. (outlook.office365.com as I can see it from my outlook settings) using SMTP but could not succeed. I tried solution from many previous posts but cant get any clue. I sincerely appreciate any help from you guys..
Here is my mail configuration:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.office365.com" userName="no-reply@mydomain.com" password="defaultPassword"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Here is my class for email:
public class eMail
    {
        public eMail() { }

```
    private string Sender{ get; set; }
    private List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    private string Subject { get; set; }
    private string Body { get; set; }

    public bool SendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            var smptClient = new SmtpClient { EnableSsl = true };

            MailMessage newEmail = new MailMessage();
            foreach (var reciepent in this.Recipients )
                newEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));

            newEmail.From = new MailAddress(this.Sender);
            newEmail.Subject = this.Subject;
            newEmail.Body = this.Body;
            newEmail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            smptClient.Send(newEmail);

            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
}
```

in above code if I use "EnableSsl = true", I get error "Server does not support secure connections.". Still if I disable ssl, I get following error:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Answer (score 1):

```
use this piece of code:

 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@somedomain.com", "SomeOne"));
    msg.From = new MailAddress("you@yourdomain.com", "You");
    msg.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
    msg.Body = "This is a test message using Exchange OnLine";
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your user name", "your password");
    client.Port = 25; // give 587 if 25  is blocked 
    client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        client.Send(msg);
        lblText.Text = "Message Sent Succesfully";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblText.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried this. It leads to the same errors like I'd mentioned in my question

Comment: check what port number are you using . may be your port is blocked

Comment: Previously I'd used port 25 but I was getting error "Server does not support secure connections." with SSL enabled, so I used port 587 but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Finally I'd resolve the issue which was related to domain we have.
For the person who are facing similar problem, here is how I had fixed it. Follwoing were my email settings:

```
<network host="smtp.office365.com" userName="no-reply@mydomain.com" password="defaultPassword"/>
```

If you are on domain then your username must have domain mentioned in your username i.e. **no-reply@domain.mydomain.com** and bang :)

Cheers!!